# UDM Pro Site-to-Site VPN issues

Tags: networking, vpn, site-to-site-vpn, ubiquiti

I just got the UDM Pro and got to setting up the Site-to-Site VPN. Everything seems to work, but I'm unable to add all 3 redundant subnets that I've got set up in my AWS VPC.

It works fine with a one, but after adding another one, the first one breaks while the second one works.

Does anyone have experience with setting this up? What am I doing wrong?

This is how my current config looks like:

AWS Subnets -

**eu-central-1a** - `172.31.16.0/20`

**eu-central-1b** - `172.31.32.0/20`

**eu-central-1c** - `172.31.0.0/20`

UDM Pro -
[Site-to-Site Subnet Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxNde.png)